# How to make an image gallery with columns of 2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, user-interface

I am trying to iterate through an array of objects and i want them printed on 2 columns but instead i get them on each line

Below is a screenshot of how the images are printed but i want them on the same line

[image]

This is the ArtObject component in which i assume there should be done some modifications

```
export class ArtObjectCard extends Component<Props> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    height: 240,
                    margin: 10,
                    flexDirection:"column",
                }}
            >
                <View
                    style={{
                        borderRadius: 10,
                        width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : screenWidth / 2 - 20,
                        height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : 200,
                        backgroundColor: "#fff",
                        shadowColor: "#999",
                        shadowOpacity: 0.3,
                        shadowRadius: 5,
                        shadowOffset: {
                            height: 1,
                            width: 0
                        }
                    }}
                >
                    <Image
                        borderRadius={10}
                        source={this.props.image}
                        style={{
                            width: this.props.width ? this.props.width : screenWidth / 2 - 20,
                            height: this.props.height ? this.props.height : 200,
                            resizeMode: "cover"
                        }}
                    />




                    <Text
                        style={{
                            width: 150,
                            fontSize: 12,
                            color: "#bbb",
                            marginTop: 5,
                            marginBottom: 10
                        }}
                    >

                    </Text>

                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

And im calling the ArtObject component in the render method

```
    renderItem = ({item, index}) => {

        if (!item) {
            return null
        }


        return (
            <View >
                <ArtObjectCard
                    title={item.title}

                    image={{uri: item.image}}

                    onClickButton={()=>{this._onPressItem(item)}}
                />

            </View>
        );
    }




    render(){
        const { search } = this.state;


        return (

            <View style={{flex: 1}}>

                <SearchBar
                    placeholder="Type something here...."
                    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
                    value={search}
                />

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.objects}
                    renderItem={this.renderItem}
                    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}

                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

EDIT 1:

After adding numColumns={2} in the flatlist it works only if i have more than 2 images to display.
If i have only 2 images it will be a blank screen

Comment: You can use `numColumns` in FlatList.

Comment: @Rajan I tried using numColumns={2} but this results in a blank screen

Comment: Remove flexDirection: "column"

Comment: Still a blank screen

Comment: @Rajan the numColumns seems to work if i have at least 3 pictures to display, but how could i make it work if i have to display only one or two pictures?